# Erro in "apk add curl" in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

This is the error I got when running "docker-compose up" for a project

```
 => [2/7] RUN apk --no-cache add curl                                                                                        17.7s
 => => # fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
 => => # WARNING: fetching https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main: temporary error (try again later)
 => => # WARNING: fetching https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community: temporary error (try again later)
 => => # ERROR: unable to select packages:
 => => #   curl (no such package):
 => => #     required by: world[curl]
```

I can open the cdn link in browser, and other people didn't encounter this issue. Any idea?

Comment: I suspect you need to install the curl package in your docker environment?

Comment: RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

Comment: @MihalBy In the docker compose process?

Comment: replase in you project RUN apk --no-cache add curl to RUN apk --no-cache add curl